# 'post to Facebook' link

Tags: php, html, facebook

I have a webpage (shown in an iOS `UIWebView`, but that doen't really matter) that shows, among other things, the users high score.

I want to add a button that the user can push to share his high score (in the HTML via PHP) on Facebook; when the user presses the button, a pre-programmed message gets posted on their wall: "Look, my high-score on awesomeiPhoneGame is 523, Check it out ".

I would prefer to do this entirely in HTML instead of native iOS code, for several reasons. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: If it works for you, I'm glad to hear you click correct my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look up at Facebook javascript SDK that mean [FB.ui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/)

and don't forget to show window that prompt the user to grant permissions to your application

(see also : [OAuth Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/))